# Another generics-baffled poor soul... How to add a static .start() method to this code?

Tags: java, generics

Yes, generics are a recurrent subject, and here it goes again...

Currently, I have this code. `Processor` is a "simple", generic interface.

```
public final class ProcessorChain<IN extends MessageProvider, OUT extends MessageProvider>
    implements Processor<IN, OUT>
{
    /**
     * The resulting processor
     */
    private final Processor<IN, OUT> p;

    /**
     * Start a processing chain with a single processor
     *
     * @param p the processor
     * @param <X> the input type
     * @param <Y> the output type
     * @return a single element processing chain
     */
    public static <X extends MessageProvider, Y extends MessageProvider>
        ProcessorChain<X, Y> startWith(final Processor<X, Y> p)
    {
        return new ProcessorChain<X, Y>(p);
    }

    /**
     * Private constructor
     *
     * @param p the processor
     */
    private ProcessorChain(final Processor<IN, OUT> p)
    {
        this.p = p;
    }

    /**
     * Add an existing processor to that chain
     *
     * <p>Note that this returns a <b>new</b> chain.</p>
     *
     * @param p2 the processor to add
     * @param <NEWOUT> the return type for that new processor
     * @return a new chain consisting of the previous chain with the new
     * processor appended
     */
    public <NEWOUT extends MessageProvider> ProcessorChain<IN, NEWOUT>
        chainWith(final Processor<OUT, NEWOUT> p2)
    {
        return new ProcessorChain<IN, NEWOUT>(merge(p, p2));
    }

    public Processor<IN, OUT> end()
    {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public OUT process(final ProcessingReport report, final IN input)
        throws ProcessingException
    {
        return p.process(report, input);
    }

    /**
     * Merge two processors
     *
     * @param p1 the first processor
     * @param p2 the second processor
     * @param <X> the input type of {@code p1}
     * @param <Y> the output type of {@code p1} and input type of {@code p2}
     * @param <Z> the output type of {@code p2}
     * @return a processor resulting of applying {@code p2} to the output of
     * {@code p1}
     */
    private static <X extends MessageProvider, Y extends MessageProvider, Z extends MessageProvider>
        Processor<X, Z> merge(final Processor<X, Y> p1, final Processor<Y, Z> p2)
    {
        return new Processor<X, Z>()
        {
            @Override
            public Z process(final ProcessingReport report, final X input)
                throws ProcessingException
            {
                return p2.process(report, p1.process(report, input));
            }
        };
    }
}
```

So, currently, I can write:

```
// p1 does <X, Y>, p2 does <Y, Z>, p3 does <Z, T>
Processor<X, T> p = ProcessingChain.startWith(p1).chainWith(p2).chainWith(p3).end();
```

And it works. In fact, I've never been that far into generics.

What I'd like to be able to write is this:

```
Processor<X, T> p = ProcessingChain.start().add(p1).add(p2).add(p3).end();
```

I've been battling trying to do this, but failed.

One reason I want to be able to do this is also, in the future, to be able to write:

```
Processor<X, T> p = ProcessingChain.start().add(p1).stopOnError().etc().etc()
```

And I feel that if I know how to `.start()`, "utility" processors along the way won't be a problem.

So, how do do that?

Comment: You're going to have to define "but failed", what you are actually trying to do, and what you expect the results to be. As-is, there's no question here. It seems like you're trying to mash together a Builder and a fluent interface here; pick one.

Comment: Isn't it obvious what I'm trying to do?

Comment: @BrianRoach In my experience Builders are often presented as fluent interfaces!  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern

Comment: @sharakan indeed, but that "no question" here leaves me flabbergasted, I think I have given all elements necessary to see the problem.

Comment: @fge as you say, generics are baffling...  therefore questions on them must be just as tricky, right?  I don't think you can do this with just a naked .start() by the way, would you settle for something not quite as cool?

Comment: @fge I see what you're getting at, but I think it would help the question to include an attempt to implement `start` with a corresponding compile error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What should a parameterless `start` method return? This is the crux of the issue, though you've only alluded to it in your question.

Note that you've declared `ProcessorChain` as implementing `Processor` - so any instance of `ProcessorChain` must act like one. For that reason, creating a `ProcessorChain` instance without a `Processor` to wrap doesn't make sense.

In general, I would say that a builder should not implement the interface of what it builds, but having written that I think I'd at least be interested in seeing counter-arguments.

Comment: That is indeed the core of the question, I thought about an identity processor and initiate with it. But since then I have found the solution...

Comment: @MiserableVariable I was posting it while you typed this, it seems

Comment: @PaulBellora, I do agree with what you say when you say "a builder should not implement the interface of what it builds".

Answer (score 2):

There's no way for a naked start method to infer the types that the resulting ProcessorChain would have to be.  Further, as @PaulBellora points out, the start() method itself as you've sketched out couldn't be a Processor, because it doesn't have enough information.

You could use a separate class as the result of a start() method, although it couldn't be parameterless.  e.g:

```
public class ProcessorChainFactory<M extends MessageProvider> {

    public static <X extends MessageProvider> ProcessorChainFactory<X> start() {
        return null;
    }

    public static <X extends MessageProvider> ProcessorChainFactory<X> start(Class<X> clazz) {
        return null;
    }

    public <X extends MessageProvider> ProcessorChain<M, X> add(Processor<M, X> processor) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }        
}
```

which can then be called in a couple of ways:

```
    Processor<MessageProvider1, Final> processor = ...;

    ProcessorChain<MessageProvider1, Final> processor1 = ProcessorChainFactory.<MessageProvider1> start().add(processor);
    ProcessorChain<MessageProvider1, Final> processor2 = ProcessorChainFactory.start(MessageProvider1.class).add(processor);
```

My feeling is that doesn't get you much further than your current `ProcessingChain.startWith(p1)`, but maybe it's helpful.

Comment: I actually did something very close to that. Thanks for the code samples!

Answer (score 1):

Well, OK, there is a way although it is a little hackish:

```
public static <X extends MessageProvider> ProcessorChain<X, X> start()
{
    final Processor<X, X> p = new Processor<X, X>()
    {
        @Override
        public X process(final ProcessingReport report, final X input)
            throws ProcessingException
        {
            return input;
        }
    };

    return new ProcessorChain<X, X>(p);
}
```

It won't work outright however. With types `S`, `ValidationData` and `P`, `p1` doing `<S, ValidationData>` and `p2` doing `<ValidationData, P>`, writing:

```
ProcessorChain.start().chainWith(p1).chainWith(p2).end()
```

leads to this compile error:

```
<NEWOUT>chainWith(Processor<MessageProvider,NEWOUT>) 
in ProcessorChain<MessageProvider,MessageProvider>
cannot be applied to
(Processor<S,ValidationData>)
```

The code above was my first attempt...

But if I write:

```
ProcessorChain.<S>start().chainWith(p1).chainWith(p2).end()
```

then it works!

Comment: Looks like you worked around it by implementing an "identity processor" :) I disagree with the design but +1 for tackling the immediate issue.

Comment: Yeah but I'm gonna scratch that with something else; I realize the design is a little fragile.